# What are the different rooting methods? and what are the differences between them?

Tags: rooting

I want to know what are the rooting methods that work on a a Galaxy S6 SM-G920F running Android 6.0.1, And when to use which ?

Android version : 6.0.1
Baseband version : G920FXXU4DPI9
Kernel Version : 3.10.61-8821257 Sep 16 2016
Build Number MMB29K.G920FXXU4DPIL
KNOX Version : KNOX 2.6

ANY help will be appreciated.

Comment: 'When to use which' what's that supposed to mean? You use root method avalable and root. Try looking [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6) for root methods.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info)? And followed up e.g. to [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) And there, checked for your device? 2 links for the S6 there.

Comment: I assume you mean systemless and traditional? Just about anything with Marshmallow or higher, like your device, requires systemless root on the stock ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific device, but here are the methods I know:

1. Exploit rooting - root via a loophole discovered for the device - an example is the Kobo Arc
2. Flash rooting - manually flashing an image for your device

Kingo Root is an excellent rooting application that works well on many models. It comes in both a PC version and an on-device version.